# Why the size of a class is getting increased by 1 if I inherit more than 2 classes in C++

Tags: c++

In the following code snippet, If I inherit the first 2 classes the size of derived class is 1, from omwards if inherit more number of classes to derived the size of derived class is getting incresed by those many number of classes. Why?

```
// Remove the comment one by one at derived class (//Base1, //Base2//, Base3//, Base5, //Base6) and check.

struct Base {
    Base(){}
};
struct Base1 {
    Base1(){}
};
struct Base2 {
    Base2(){}
};
struct Base3 {
    Base3(){}
};
struct Base5 {
    Base5(){}
};
struct Base6 {
    Base6(){}
};
struct Derived : Base, Base1, Base2//, Base3//, Base5, //Base6
{
public:
    Derived(){}     
};

int main() {
    Derived der;
    cout << "Sizeof der: " << sizeof(der) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try to make your question more clear, and also post the outputs.

Comment: `void main()` is **not valid C++**.

Comment: The size of a class is compiler dependent, so the question shouldn't be 'in C++' but, for example, 'in Visual C++ 2008, when compiling for debugging'.

Comment: Do you really need all those empty constructors? And does your country not use the number `4`?

Comment: ¤ C++ supports a so called **empty base class** optimization, where a base class sub-object doesn't contribute to the derived class' size, C++11 §1.8/5. One restriction on that is that sub-object of the same type must have different addresses. But anyway as you keep adding bases of different types, if the compiler is smart (like g++ for this) they should just be optimized away, and if it isn't smart (like visual c++ for this), each one may add 1 to the size in order to get a unique sub-object address. By the way, `void main` is not standard. It prevents testing with g++. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 12):

It means your compiler's empty base optimization is not as extensive as on other compilers.

Output of your program with all six Bases uncommented (and with the necessary include and the "void main" error fixed)

> gcc 4.6.2: Sizeof der: 1
>
> clang 3.0: Sizeof der: 1
>
> intel 11.1 Sizeof der: 1
>
> Sun C++ 5.8: Sizeof der: 1
>
> Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (release build): Sizeof der: 5

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I am working on Windows and code was compiled in Visual Studio 2005. 
Yes! If you uncomment all the bases the value is 5. 
But if you uncomment Base, Base1 the Sizeof der: 1, 
but if you uncomment Base2 also the output is "Sizeof der: 2" and the size of der is incresing by 1 by one more each base class (uncomment one more base class). 
Why the Size of der is 1 even if u derived 2 classes and why it is increasing from onwards increasing with the number of inheriting classes.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you extend a class it becomes a part of the final object and therefore increases its size by the size of the base class object. As already mentioned there may be some compiler optimizations going on that cause the observed effect.